# Calculating influence for PLS with outer loadings and beta coefficient of latent variable

Tags: r, regression, partial-least-squares

I'm calculating a penalized least squares regression (PLS). Two influence variables are connected to a latent variable. This latent variable has an influence (beta coefficient) of 0.6 on the response (or latent variable of the response).

Both influence variables are correlated (outer loading) with 0.6 and 0.8 to the latent variable.

Does anyone know how to (back)-calculate a beta coefficient for each influence variable and not just the latent variable connected to the influence variables?

I'm using a mix of the smartPLS programming tool and R.

EDIT:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446300/sempls-package-backcalculating-influence

Comment: SmartPLS and the [tag:pls] tag refer to partial least squares. Are you sure you're asking about, and performing penalized least squares regression?

Comment: I'm asking the question on stackoverflow now. But with a reproducible example in `R` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446300/sempls-package-backcalculating-influence